# Adding customized columns to gtsummary

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary, gt

I am trying to figure out how to add customized columns for labels when using gtsummary -- for example I want to add a column with headings for each summary statistics that I have. I don't want this in the characteristic column, I want this to be on the left of the characteristic group.

[image: expected output]

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this is using `gtsummary`, I have the rest of the table but would need the column with the modifiable header in yellow.

This is the code I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)


trial %>% 
  dplyr::select(age, trt) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(., 
                         by = trt,
                         missing = "no",
                         type = age ~ "continuous2",
                         statistic =  age ~ c(
                           "{N_nonmiss}",
                           "{mean} ({sd})",
                           "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
                           "{min}, {max}"),
                         
  digits = age ~ c(0, 1, 1, 1),
label = age ~ "  ") %>%
  gtsummary::add_overall() %>%
  # This will add the Total column
  gtsummary::add_stat_label(label = age ~ c("N",
                                            "Mean (SD)",
                                            "Median (Q1, Q3)",
                                            "Min, Max")) %>% 
  gtsummary::modify_header(
    label ~ "Summary Statistics",
    stat_0 ~ "Total",
    stat_1 ~ "Drug A",
    stat_2 ~ "Drug B"
  ) %>% 
  gtsummary::modify_table_body(~ .x %>% dplyr::relocate(stat_0, .after = stat_2))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I have added the code using the trial data!

Answer (score 2):

You're so close! See code example below :)

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2.9026'

trial %>% 
  dplyr::select(age, trt) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary( 
    by = trt,
    missing = "no",
    type = age ~ "continuous2",
    statistic =  age ~ c(
      "{N_nonmiss}",
      "{mean} ({sd})",
      "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
      "{min}, {max}"),
    
    digits = age ~ c(0, 1, 1, 1)
  ) %>%
  gtsummary::add_overall(last = TRUE) %>% 
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      mutate(
        new_label = ifelse(row_type == "label", label, ""),
        label = ifelse(row_type == "label", "", label),
        .before = label
      )
  ) %>%
  modify_header(
    new_label ~ "Characteristic",
    label ~ "Summary Statistics",
    stat_0 ~ "Total",
    stat_1 ~ "Drug A",
    stat_2 ~ "Drug B"
  ) %>%
  modify_column_alignment(new_label, "left") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| Characteristic | Summary Statistics | Drug A | Drug B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age |  |  |  |  |
|  | N | 91 | 98 | 189 |
|  | Mean (SD) | 47.0 (14.7) | 47.4 (14.0) | 47.2 (14.3) |
|  | Median (IQR) | 46.0 (37, 59.0) | 48.0 (39, 56.0) | 47.0 (38, 57.0) |
|  | Range | 6.0, 78.0 | 9.0, 83.0 | 6.0, 83.0 |

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm. I ended up using `dplyr::if_else` given it is a little bit more strict . Also, thanks for the little tips that you added in the code for `add_overall()`. The package has saved me many hours, can never thank you enough!